# Slow query with WHERE PK IN (...)

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, sql-server-2014

I have a very simple, but large table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tblMulti (
 pk1 bigint,
 pk2 bigint
)
```

where the PK is the composition of pk1-pk2 (in this order).

Then, I have a large table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
 ID bigint,
 field1 int,
 ... (other fields)
)
```

with ID being the only PK of the table.

I need to do the following query:

```
SELECT  ID, COUNT(*) OVER () as TotalCount
FROM    tbl
WHERE   ID IN (
    SELECT  pk1
    FROM    tblMulti 
    WHERE   pk2 = 101)
ORDER BY  field1 DESC, ID DESC
OFFSET @start ROWS FETCH NEXT @count ROWS ONLY;
```

The problem is that the filter "pk2=101" results in a huge number of rows (94% of the whole tblMulti table), and for this reason SQL Server decides to perform an index scan instead of an index seek.

How can I enhance the performance of this query?

Thank you very much

cghersi

Comment: What happens when you do a `Join` instead of `subquery`

Comment: This query is inside a Stored Procedure?

Comment: this query is inside an SP

Comment: When I do a Join it takes a little more (say 1.2 sec instead of 1.0 sec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here what I'd do to optimize:

1. Create a `NON CLUSTERED` index on `pk2` column.
2. Create a `NON CLUSTERED` index on `field1` column.
3. Rebuild/Reorganize indexes and statistics.
4. Use a JOIN instead of IN.
5. Use the `OPTIMIZE FOR` query hint.

So, try this:

```
DECLARE @C INT = 101;
SELECT ID, COUNT(*) OVER () as TotalCount
FROM tbl
INNER JOIN tblMulti
    ON tbl.ID = tblMulti.pk1        
WHERE pk2 = @C
ORDER BY  field1 DESC, ID DESC
OFFSET @start ROWS FETCH NEXT @count ROWS ONLY
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@C = 101));
```

Comment: The non clustered index helped!

Comment: Still, looking at the execution plan, the highest amount of time is spent in a Right Join and in an index scan of the tbl table to order by field1. the Join is performed both when I do WHERE PK IN (...) and when I do a real INNER JOIN. The problem is that it costs 50% of the time (following Exec Plan results...), and the warning related to "operator used tempdb to spill data" appears.

Comment: @CristianoGhersi try to add a `NON CLUSTERED` index on `field1` too. Also try to reorganize/rebuld indexes and statistics. Statistics are very important for the query optimizer to generate an efficient execution plan.

Comment: Yes, the index on field1 helped too.
Moreover, I decided to split the query in two: the list of IDs and then the count() on a separate query. It helped too. Now the two queries takes 350ms together

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this....

```
SELECT  t1.ID, COUNT(*) OVER () as TotalCount
FROM    tbl t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT  1
              FROM    tblMulti 
              WHERE   t1.ID = pk1
                AND   pk2 = 101)
ORDER BY  t1.field1 DESC, t1.ID DESC
OFFSET @start ROWS FETCH NEXT @count ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this results in the very same exec plan, with same times

Answer (score 0):

The reason this seems slow is because you don't have an index on the `pk2` field yet you use it to limit your results to this 'just one type' (`101`) (**).

=> Assuming you only need the table for the query here, you could simply reverse the order of the primary key of tblMulti and it will (functionally) be the exact same thing.

=> Assuming you need the pk with said field-order for something else, you could create an additional unique index (or constraint) on the table with the fields in reversed order.

**: Yes I realize that you *have* `pk2` in the index, but that's just as useful for MSSQL as me telling you to find the phone-number of someone whose name ends "mith, John", having the phone-book indexed on family-name will not help you much there either.

Also, since you know that the combination `pk1`, `pk2` is unique, you could use a `JOIN` instead of the `WHERE EXISTS()`

```
SELECT  t1.ID, 
        COUNT(*) OVER () as TotalCount
FROM    tbl t1
JOIN    tblMulti tm
  ON    tm.pk1 = t1.ID
 AND    tm.pk2 = 101
ORDER BY t1.field1 DESC, 
         t1.ID DESC
OFFSET @start ROWS FETCH NEXT @count ROWS ONLY;
```

That said, I'm a bit surprised this works. You do an `ORDER BY` on a field that is not part of the output. I'm somehow guessing that MSSQL leaves it out and simply uses `t1.ID` ?!?

Wouldn't the following query be more straightforward to use ?

```
SELECT  t1.ID, 
        COUNT(*) as TotalCount
FROM    tbl t1
JOIN    tblMulti tm
  ON    tm.pk1 = t1.ID
 AND    tm.pk2 = 101
GROUP BY t1.ID
ORDER BY t1.ID DESC
OFFSET @start ROWS FETCH NEXT @count ROWS ONLY;
```